# Select the first element in view for Voice Over

Tags: swift, xcode, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I am using Xcode to make an iOS app. When I segue into the next view controller, it has objects in the following order from top to bottom on the screen: label, collection view, button. When I use voiceover, I want the first item on the screen to be in focus (the label). However, whatever I do, it is always a particular cell from the collection view that is selected by default (somewhere in the middle of the screen). In landscape it is a different cell and in portrait a different cell. But every time it is that same cell. I tried using UIAccessibilityPostNotification, as well as using delays and other things. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58059512/edit) your question by including all the relevant code you have tried so far. Please give it read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Should be posted when a new view appears that encompasses a major portion of the screen.

Optionally, pass the element that VoiceOver should move to after processing the notification.

```
UIKIT_EXTERN UIAccessibilityNotifications

UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification;
```

You need to provide

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification, youLabel);
```